# Fetching all user and user friend's videos from facebook and store it Database

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using rails and I need to fetch all user videos and user friend's videos from facebook and store it in our database.

Video's which is like

1. User and user friend's liked videos,
2. User and user friend's shared videos,
3. User and user friend's tagged videos,
4. User and user friend's commented videos,
5. User and user friend's uploaded videos, etc

So Is there any easy method to retrive all these videos at same time?

Answer (score 0):

Videos in the user's stream will be in the stream object (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/).  Play around in the Graph API explorer using fql?q={your query here} to see the results.  You can play around with the `where` clause to get various groupings back.  However, from my experience, to get all 5 categories of videos, you will have to run multiple queries.  See documentation on multiquery query (Good examples here on this old REST API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/) Some of the non deprecated APIs support this.

Remember the Graph API explorer is your friend.